# Syntax error on token "(", ; expected Syntax error on token ",", ; expected Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors

I am working on a project just to test out eclipse IDE for java developers. I am new at java so I want to know why it isn't working because I already know what to do. Here is the code:

```
public class eclipse {

public static double main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final double average(double number, double number2)
    {
        double number3 = (number + number2)/2;
                return number3;
    }
    final double suk(double number4, double number5)
    {
        double number6 = number4 + number5;
        return number6;
    }
    final double differenck(double number7, double number8)
    {
        double number9 = number7 - number8;
        return number9;
    }
    final double produck(double number10, double number11)
    {
        double number12 = number10*number11;
        return number12;
    }
  } 
}
```

Here is the error that comes up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
Void methods cannot return a value
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
Void methods cannot return a value
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
Void methods cannot return a value
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
Void methods cannot return a value
```

Comment: Remove the methods from the `main` method

Comment: You can't declare methods inside methods if you want it to compile.

Comment: @Pshemo You can. But it will not compile :P

Comment: @MarounMaroun True. Rephrased my previous comment :)

Comment: @Pshemo Now you'll get my valuable +1 :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun Now I am just waiting for a comment about case when we are declaring methods inside class that is declared inside other method like `void test(){class X{ void testX(){System.out.println("Hello");}}}` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing all your methods in main method.Please remove all your methods from `main` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     //do something

  } 

 final double average(double number, double number2)
    {
        double number3 = (number + number2)/2;
           return number3;
    }
    final double suk(double number4, double number5)
    {
        double number6 = number4 + number5;
        return number6;
    }
    final double differenck(double number7, double number8)
    {
        double number9 = number7 - number8;
        return number9;
    }
    final double produck(double number10, double number11)
    {
        double number12 = number10*number11;
        return number12;
    }
```

And `return`  type of `main` method should be `void`

Comment: Thank You. Like I said, I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the methods from the `main` method. If you're using `main` as the application entry point then the return type is `void`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Answer (score 0):

They need to be outside the main method, also the return type for the main method is void:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   //code 

 }
final double average(double number, double number2)
{
    double number3 = (number + number2)/2;
            return number3;
}
final double suk(double number4, double number5)
{
    double number6 = number4 + number5;
    return number6;
}
final double differenck(double number7, double number8)
{
    double number9 = number7 - number8;
    return number9;
}
final double produck(double number10, double number11)
{
    double number12 = number10*number11;
    return number12;
}
```